# Diffrence between opening a browser/site through selenium and Manually

Tags: selenium, web, automation, webdriver

I have started learning selenium Webdriver API recently. I was trying to automate a simple task of launching gmail.com and logging into account using Chrome browser.

The difference I noticed is when I open browser manually it lists my accounts on the Home page and then I can select the account, enter the password and login in complete

When I launch gmail.com using selenium it directly gives me log in window when I can enter email and password

Any reason why we see the difference while launching browser through selenium

Comment: This is normal GMail behaviour. When you start Selenium, you have a new profile (with no cookies).

Comment: This does not really deserve a downvote considering that the user is new. As @SiKing mentioned, when you launch a browser using Selenium web driver, the browser instance will be clean of any cookies or history.